# What does a version history of a migrated repository looks like?

Tags: tfs, migration, visual-sourcesafe, revision-history

Since we migrated from VSS to TFS the version history shows a single user and day for every commit. The original users and dates for each commit are displayed in the check-in comment.
Is this the best we can do? Isn't there a way to migrate putting the original User into the "User" column and the original date into the "Date" column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. There is no supported way to migrate history from a non-TFS repository and maintain a true history (outside of comments).  TFS team does this on purpose so as to maintain the integrity of the audit trail (instead of having TFS "lie" about when that change was checked into TFS).

In practice it is usually sufficient as you still have the changes in the proper order, and if you're going back to inspect history the information you want (date/time, user) is still captured, just not in the ideal location.